# How to keep row selected after adding new one in the begining of table?

Tags: c++, qt

My model designed to add row in the begining of table. Problem is that if I select second row (for example) selection still will be on this row (second) after adding new row, but original row moved down.

I figured out that QStandardItemModel provides propely behaviour. How to provide same one in my inherited QAbstractTableModel?

Now there is exapmle code for QStandardItemModel. You can select row and see what's going on.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QTimer>

void timeout(QTimer &timer, QStandardItemModel &tblModel)
{
    static int step = 0;
    tblModel.insertRow(0);
    QStandardItem *pItem = new QStandardItem(QString("row %0").arg(step));
    tblModel.setItem(0, 1, pItem);
    step++;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow win;
    QStandardItemModel tblModel(0, 1);
    QTableView tblView;
    tblView.setModel(&tblModel);
    win.setCentralWidget(&tblView);
    win.show();
    QTimer timer;
    timer.setInterval(1000); 
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout,
        [&timer, &tblModel]() { timeout(timer, tblModel); });
    timer.start();
    return app.exec();
}
```

And simplified version of my model. You can see that in my version selected row doesen't move.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QString>


class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    MyModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    void insertRow(int data);

private:
    QVector<int>  table;
};

MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel(parent) {}

int MyModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    return table.count();
}

int MyModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    return 1;
}

QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) {
        return QVariant();
    }
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return table[table.count() - 1 - index.row()];
    }
    return QVariant();
}

void MyModel::insertRow(int data) {
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    table.push_back(data);
    endInsertRows();
}

void timeout(QTimer &timer, MyModel * tblModel)
{
    static int step = 0;
    tblModel->insertRow(step);
    step++;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow win;
    MyModel * model = new MyModel();
    QTableView tblView;
    tblView.setModel(model);
    win.setCentralWidget(&tblView);
    win.show();
    QTimer timer;
    timer.setInterval(1000); 
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout,
        [&timer, model]() { timeout(timer, model); });
    timer.start();
    return app.exec();
}
```

I didn't find any information in QAbstractTableModel documentation. After that I tried to read QStandardItemModel source code but it's really difficult for understanding.

Comment: I think you should call beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0)

Comment: @Fabio: correct - otherwise the view thinks the row is appended (and the selection is not properly initialized)